# dc.js x-axis ticks unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

Having a bit of trouble with dc.js.

I have a line chart, for which I am trying to set the maximum ticks. The current graph is as such:

[image: Graph image]

I am trying to customise its x-axis ticks with the following parameters

```
graph.xUnits(d3.time.days).round(d3.time.day.round)
graph.xAxis().ticks(8).tickFormat(d3.time.format("%m/%d"))
```

As you can see, the graph is showing more than 8 ticks, and is showing an unnecessary extra value at 08/01.

Any clues as to how this can be resolved? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#linear_ticks) on `linear.ticks([count])`, which that value is eventually passed to:

> The specified count is only a hint; the scale may return more or fewer
>   values depending on the input domain.

d3 doesn't supply a way to specify an exact tick count, save for specifying the ticks yourself. You can generate the ticks yourself, and set them with [axis.tickValues([values])](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickValues).